# required interface vs interface realization vs <<use>> dependency

Tags: interface, uml

As the title suggest what is the difference between the three and when should one use one of the three instead of the other two?
The internet is filled with their definition but i couldn't find any text or explanation on when and where to use required interface or the `<<use>>` dependency.

Comment: i didn't ask for syntax and graphical notation, the internet is filled with them. What i wanted to know was where to use realization and required interface and how do they differ with a practical example.

Answer (score 5):

There are only two cases in fact: realize/use on the one hand, and provided/required on the other. They essentially describe the same thing, but with different emphasis.

With realize/use you draw visible relationships from the class (or component, as in my examples below) to the interface, and thus show the interface and its operations in the diagram.

[image: realize/use]

You could, of course, split that into two different diagrams.

With provided/required, on the other hand, the interface is only shown as lollipops so you can't see the operations. But you can draw visible relationships (usually "assembly") between the lollipops.

[image: provided/required]

I'd say that realize/use is more appropriate if you want to show who implements what. Provided/required is more appropriate if you want to focus more on interactions between parts.

Comment: so given an interface and a class which realizes the given interface, i can use either of the notation in different diagrams to emphasize on different aspects of the relationship? however i still don't get the use of required interface besides that they take a lot less space to depict.

Comment: That's pretty much it in my view. The lollipop notation is more focused on how things fit together. I tend to use it mainly in component diagrams, whereas in class diagrams you typically want to show what methods each class implements. Note that in EA, you can elect to show realize/use relationships as lollipops (right-click - Features and Properties...). These lollipops are special in that you cannot manipulate them in the GUI or draw assemblies between them, they're just an alternative to showing the interface in the diagram. That's what Thomas Kilian has shown in his example.

Answer (score 2):

A required interface is usually shown as socket. It means that in order to have the class working it needs at runtime a counterpart with a lollipop. This counterpart in turn offers the interface via a lollipop. To decouple class and interface definition you put the interface in a stereotyped class and draw a realization from the providing class to the interface. Vice versa you draw a dependency from the requiring class to the interface. Whether you stereotype the dependency with `<<use>>` is more a matter of taste.

[image]

as described above and as alternate representation:
[image]

Comment: is this concept of `runtime counterpart` only in uml?if not then how would i translate it in one of the oopl?

Comment: In any OO language you have interfaces (headers). The realizing implement the interface and the dependent classes just use the headers to call methods/use properties declared in the interface.