# A component in UML that defines an interface but does not require or provide it

Tags: components, uml, diagram

As part of a larger component diagram I want to show 3 components which are working with an interface called IPrint.

- One component implements the IPrint interface, therefore is "providing" it
- One component uses the IPrint interface, therefore is "requiring" it

I can model this using ball-and-socket notation. The providing component would get the ball, and the requiring component would get the socket.

However, now, I want to highlight a third component which defines the interface (I want to highlight that there is no dependency between requiring and providing component)

What is the best way of drawing this with UML 2.0? My first attempt is shown here with a realization arrow

[image]

but it is an awkward notation because it looks like the defining component is providing an implementation, which it is not.

Here's my attempt based on Geert's answer:

[image]

Here's my third attempt based on bruno's comment:

[image]

Comment: What’s an example of a component that only defines an interface? What are you trying to express?

Comment: Let's assume all three components are .NET assemblies. One of the .NET assemblies defines the public interface "IPrint" but lets another assembly implement it.

Comment: What in your world is "defines the interface"? An interface defines an interface. Not a component.

Comment: I understand the idea with the nested relation but I have a doubt. You do not want to use the notation using the compartment like in [Figure 11.45 formal-15-03-01](http://bouml.free.fr/comp.png) ?

Comment: I added your option above. This would be without using ball-and-socket notation though, right?

Comment: @LemonSky you can use also the sockets but like that it is more visible the same Interface is required/provided/defined. Just add the stereotype <<use>> on the dependency

Comment: See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28686194/required-interface-vs-interface-realization-vs-use-dependency/28690458#28690458 or https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30766572/interfaces-in-uml-component-diagram/30768878#30768878 or https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31705705/uml2-ports-and-interfaces-in-component-diagrams/31709704#31709704

Comment: Those links are not related to the question of how to depict a "defining" component.

Comment: @bruno: how to depict the third one with sockets? You mean, a socket symbol in place of the dependency arrow?

Comment: @LemonSky I compared your last proposal with a mix of your two last proposals, I mean the two first components connected through  ball&sockets and the third component with its compartment "packaged elements" showing the defined class but without connection to the other components.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What you are looking for is the ownership relation.
The interface is **owned** by the component that "defines" is as you call it.
[image]

In the metamodel from UML 2.5 above your interface is playing the role of `packagedElement` with regards to the third component. The Component acts as the `namespace` for the Interface

This relation is not visually represented but rather expressed by the fact that the interface element is nested inside the component element. (there is a nesting notation, but that is rarely used and hardly defined in the specs)

Comment: Thanks. I added a new proposal based on your answer to the original question. Does it reflect what you are saying and would you say that it is correct?